# White screen on opening webview on iPad air 2

Tags: ipad, uiwebview

I have a webview which loads a webpage containing a HTML and few javascript files.
The javascript executes but, but on opening the webview I just see a blank white screen on iPad air 2(iOS 8.1.1).
Am I missing something?

P.S: The same webpage loads without any issues on an iPad 4.

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question not as a comment